# Java: Publisher-Observer pattern: High CPU Usage

Tags: java

I have a ServerSocket Thread that accepts a connection and starts a socket handler. This part seems to be working fine with no memory leaks or high cpu usage. I added a Publisher thread and an observer thread and now, my java program is reporting high CPU usage.

Subject.java:

```
public interface Subject {
public void attach(Observer o);
public void detach(Observer o);
public void notifyUpdate(Message m);
```

}

MessagePublisher.java:

```
public class MessagePublisher extends Thread implements Subject{
private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean readyToPublish = false;
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> msgHolder;
public MessagePublisher(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> _queue){
    this.msgHolder = _queue;
}


@Override
public void attach(Observer o) {
    observers.add(o);
}

@Override
public void detach(Observer o) {
    observers.remove(o);
}

@Override
public void notifyUpdate(Message m) {
    for(Observer o: observers) {
        o.update(m);
    }
}

public void run(){
    this.readyToPublish = true;
    while (readyToPublish)
        {
            try
            {                    
                Message _m = (Message)this.msgHolder.poll();
                if(!_m.equals(null)){
                    System.out.println("Polled message: " + _m.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("Number of subscribers: " + observers.size());
                    notifyUpdate(_m);
                }                    
                
            }
            catch(Exception j) { }
            try { sleep(9); }
            catch(Exception e) { }
        }
        EndWork();
}
public void EndWork(){
    this.readyToPublish = false;
    this.observers.clear();
    
}
```

}

Main.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> msgHolder = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>();
    ServerSocketThread _socketThread = new ServerSocketThread(msgHolder);
    _socketThread.start();
    
    MessagePublisher _publisher = new MessagePublisher(msgHolder);
    _publisher.start();
    
    UIServerSocketThread _uiSocketThread = new UIServerSocketThread(_publisher);
    _uiSocketThread.start();        
    
}
```

UIServerSocketThread.java:

```
public class UIServerSocketThread extends Thread{
private ServerSocket        objServerSocket; 
private Socket              objSocket;
private int                 iPort = 21001;
private FileHandler         obj_LogFileHandler;
private Logger              obj_Logger;

private int file_size =   8000000;
private int numLogFiles  = 20;

private UIClientSocketThread  objCltSocket;
private MessagePublisher    objPublisher;
private boolean             running = false;
public UIServerSocketThread(MessagePublisher _publisher){
    
    this.running = true;
    try {            
        this.obj_LogFileHandler = new FileHandler("uiserver.log.%g", file_size, numLogFiles);
        this.obj_LogFileHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    }
    
    catch ( IOException obj_Exception ) {
        this.obj_LogFileHandler = null;
    }
    catch ( SecurityException obj_Exception ) {
        this.obj_LogFileHandler = null;
    }

    this.obj_Logger = null;

    if ( this.obj_LogFileHandler != null ) {
        this.obj_Logger = Logger.getLogger("eti.logger.uiserver");
        this.obj_Logger.addHandler(this.obj_LogFileHandler);
    }
    try {
    this.objServerSocket = new ServerSocket(this.iPort);
    } catch(IOException i){
        //i.printStackTrace();
        this.obj_Logger.info(i.getMessage());
    }
    this.objPublisher = _publisher;
}

public void run() {        
    StringBuffer        sMsg;
    
    sMsg = new StringBuffer();        
    
    while ( this.running ) {
        try {
            this.objSocket = this.objServerSocket.accept();
        } catch(Exception e){
            sMsg.append("Error accepting ui socket connection\n");
            sMsg.append(e.getMessage());                
            this.obj_Logger.info(sMsg.toString());
        }
        
        try {
                
                this.objCltSocket = new UIClientSocketThread(this.objSocket, this.obj_Logger);
                if(!this.objPublisher.equals(null)){
                    this.obj_Logger.info("Attacing clientObserver");
                    this.objPublisher.attach(this.objCltSocket);
                }
                
                this.objCltSocket.start();
            
        } catch(Exception r) {
            sMsg.append("Error \n");
            sMsg.append(r.getMessage());                
            this.obj_Logger.info(sMsg.toString());
        }   
        
    }
    this.objPublisher.EndWork();
    stopServerSocketThread();
        
} // end run
public void stopServerSocketThread() {
     try {
         this.running = false;
        this.objServerSocket.close();
        this.objServerSocket = null;
        this.obj_Logger.info("Server NOT ACCEPTING Connections!!");
    } catch(Exception e ) {            
        this.obj_Logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

I am not sure where the issue is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Threads tend to cache local variables. In your case the observers and the readyToPublish should be declared volatile so that any change will be immediately perceived. And that could be in some case the loop still runs while readyToPublish is false...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two infinite loops in your application. One is in class `MessagePublisher`  with function `run()`. And another one is in class `UIServerSocketThread`. This will cause high CPU usage.

Comment: I was assuming that poll in my MessagePublisher was blocking. I am wrong in my assumption. It's a non-blocking call.